# Is there a way to search only c++ packages in nuget package manager under visual 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Directly on the website nuget.org or searching via the integrated visual studio 2015 nuget package manager, I can't find out c++ packages. Sometimes a cpp appears but this is based on luck.

How to search c++ nuget packages ?

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is to add a tag filter to the search phrase:
`tags:native`

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/02/13/find-your-favorite-library-for-c-in-nuget/

If you can't find c++ packages they are either not available in NuGet gallery, or you use an old API endpoint for packages-source. At the time of this writing this is the latest endpoint: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`